# how to search and highlight pdf's keyword programmatically

Tags: c#, .net, pdf

i've tried two different component to integrate pdf file in windows form application (c#).
the above mentionated component are PDFSharp and Sloppycode webBrowserEx.
Now, both of them work fine, but I'm not able to search and highlight programmatically full text defining by user through a textBox.

Can anyone give me some suggest to achieve my purpose?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: possible duplicate of [how to highlight a text or word in a pdf file using iTextsharp?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6523243/how-to-highlight-a-text-or-word-in-a-pdf-file-using-itextsharp)

Answer (score 1):

I found this answer to help me when I was working with PDFs. Not sure if you seen it yet but it may help you. I went with iTextSharp.

[how to highlight a text or word in a pdf file using iTextsharp?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6523243/how-to-highlight-a-text-or-word-in-a-pdf-file-using-itextsharp)

hope it helps.