# C# - How to: Open PDF, highlight search-results, and save highlighting back to PDF

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, pdf, itext

I'm using itextsharp.dll.

How do I search and highlight text in the pdf file?

After highlighting the text in pdf, I want to save the highlighted pdf file such that when the PDF is re-opened, it is still highlighted.

Any ideas?

Comment: Have you read the documentation? What have you tried yourself? Do you have any code you've written that you need help with? Any specific issues? We generally like a show of effort here at Stackoverflow.

Comment: hi steen i have pdf file and i want to search a text operation and highlight the searched text in the pdf file. how to do that.

Comment: @Anbuselvan, this is actually a lot more complicated than it sounds. Please see the post here. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6523243/how-to-highlight-a-text-or-word-in-a-pdf-file-using-itextsharp

Answer (score 1):

Have you consider another library such as [Apache PDFBox](http://pdfbox.apache.org/)? It is support following features:

PDF to text extraction
Merge PDF Documents
PDF Document
Encryption/Decryption
Lucene Search Engine Integration
Fill in form data FDF and XFDF 
Create a PDF from a text file
Create images from PDF pages  Print a PDF