# How to extract text and word coordinates from pdf?

Tags: .net, vb.net, pdf

How can I extract the text from a PDF document in .NET? Also, how can I get the coordinates of each word on the page? Can I do this with [iTextSharp](http://sourceforge.net/projects/itextsharp), or some other component?

Comment: iTextSharp is a possibility, but PDF extracting is generally not as easy as one might think, because the texts inside a pdf are not always in the order one might expect.

Comment: Thanks Citykid.we didn't expect in the same order.Do you have any    sample code or document using iTextSharp?

Comment: sorry no sample code, i just digged a little into the topic some weeks ago and what I remember is that iTextSharp is themost frequently used tool, and that the transformation is generally not as simple as I hoped it to be. The first document I used for testing would have cuased the order issue.

Comment: Look [at this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15086367/1729265) and the answers linked from there. That will give you some ideas on how to start using iText(Sharp). For PDFBox look at its example [PrintTextLocations](http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/pdfbox/trunk/examples/src/main/java/org/apache/pdfbox/examples/util/PrintTextLocations.java).

Comment: Thanks a lot mkl. i want to extract text and word co-ordinates from the text pdf using iTextSharp. in the below mentioned link i have uploaded text pdf.for that pdf can anybody able to find word co-ordinates? i had no idea on              itextsharp   https://docs.google.com/file/d/0B_nzYHWVJJ7KQ0dPLWdyS2FBWUk/edit?usp=sharing

Answer (score 0):

The task can be easily accomplished with help of [Docotic.Pdf library](https://bitmiracle.com/pdf-library/).

Below is a code that writes all words with their coordinates into the system console and also draws rectangle around each found word.

```
public static void extractAndDrawWordBounds(string inputFileName, string outputFileName)
{
    using (PdfDocument pdf = new PdfDocument(inputFileName))
    {
        PdfPage page = pdf.Pages[0];
        foreach (PdfTextData data in page.GetWords())
        {
            System.Console.WriteLine(data.ToString());
            page.Canvas.DrawRectangle(data.Bounds);
        }

        pdf.Save(outputFileName);
    }

    System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(outputFileName);
}
```

Other than that, the library can extract formatted text ([PdfPage.GetTextWithFormatting](https://bitmiracle.com/pdf-library/api/pdfpage-gettextwithformatting) method) or even individual characters ([PdfPage.GetChars](https://bitmiracle.com/pdf-library/api/pdfpage-getchars) method)

Disclaimer: I am one of the developers of the library.

Comment: Thanks a lot mkl. i want to extract text and word co-ordinates from the text pdf using iTextSharp. in the below mentioned link i have uploaded text pdf.for that pdf can anybody able to find word co-ordinates? i had no idea on              itextsharp   https://docs.google.com/file/d/0B_nzYHWVJJ7KQ0dPLWdyS2FBWUk/edit?usp=sharing

Answer (score -2):

Try [PDFLib TET](http://www.pdflib.com/?id=12)

it's the best tool I've found to do this, but it's not free (and it's not cheap anyway).

Comment: Thanks a lot . i want to extract text and word co-ordinates from the text pdf using iTextSharp. in the below mentioned link i have uploaded text pdf.for that pdf can anybody able to find word co-ordinates? i had no idea on              itextsharp   https://docs.google.com/file/d/0B_nzYHWVJJ7KQ0dPLWdyS2FBWUk/edit?usp=sharing