# How to find the exact co-ordinates of a string in a PDF file?

Tags: c#, .net, pdf, itext

I am using iTextSharp to read some strings from a PDF file which are present in a table. For this i need to provide the co-ordinates of the positions from where i need to read the strings. I need these co-ordinates in the form which can be passed into the System.util.RectangleJ object to create a rectangle around the string. Can you tell me how do i find these coordinates?

Comment: This [SO][1] might help you achieve what you are trying to do.


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4577789/extract-text-and-text-rectangle-coordinates-from-a-pdf-file-using-itextsharp

Comment: possible duplicate of [Using LocationTextExtractionStrategy in itextSharp for text coordinate](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7513209/using-locationtextextractionstrategy-in-itextsharp-for-text-coordinate)

Comment: *I need these co-ordinates in the form which can be passed into the System.util.RectangleJ object* -what is so special about that `System.util.RectangleJ` class?

Comment: @mkl i mean i need them in the form (llx,lly,urx,ury). origin is at lower left corner.

Comment: Have a look [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12876331/1729265) or [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13719947/1729265) or [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15086367/1729265).

Answer (score -1):

IText has a companion application called "iText RUPS" that will show you the format of a PDF
document. It's a little crude and difficult to understand at first, but you will see coordinates, Embedded JavaScripts etc in the document. It is a stand-application application so it is valid for  iTextsharp too because it's using IText terminology to show you a document.