# iTextSharp Coordinates of a specific text on a Pdf Page

Tags: c#, .net, pdf, itext, coordinates

I have a pdf page. There is plain text on it from start to end i.e.

> This is a sample pdf and my aim is to get the cordinates of specific
>   word or line.

**I need to find the coordinates of the word "specific"**. I am using iTextSharp in c#.net
What is the best way to do it?

Comment: Did you try _anything_ to solve your problem? Please read [FAQ], [ask] and [help]

Comment: There is no such thing as "plain text" in PDF. Please read http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6523243/how-to-highlight-a-text-or-word-in-a-pdf-file-using-itextsharp You can examine `TextRenderInfo` snippets, but there is no guarantee that a `TextRenderInfo` elements correspond with a "specific word". Your question starts with wrong premises that reveal a lack of understanding of PDF.